# how to updated values that are same in other columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server

the logic behind this is If the Ser_request numbers are same for the same location then, Consider the row with Max “Power before downtime”. The row that needs to be updated is the **column name ID** with minimum value

i need to create three new columns Adj Start date,Adj end date,Adj DC power and insert the data from the repective columns

- downtime_start =Adj Start date

  -downtime_end = Adj end date

  -power_before_downtime = Adj DC power

i tried doing it but by grouping the values that are same i was unable to find the first line.

i am using sql server 2012

this is what i have tried so far:

```
select location,downtime_start  , count(*)
from dbo.TB1
group by location,downtime_start  , count(*)
having count(*)>1
```

after this query i get the result of TB1 and i dont know how to group them and insert the values in to the respective columns.

any help is appreciated

thank you

```
ID | location | downtime_start      | downtime_end         | power_before_downtime | power_after_downtime | creation_time       | end_time            | ser_request
1  | xyz.a    | 3/8/2017 2:00:00 PM | 3/10/2017 8:00:00 AM | 14.16                 | 13.67                | 3/8/2017 3:25:37 PM | 3/8/2017 6:41:59 PM | 0003 
2  | xyz.a    | 3/8/2017 2:00:00 PM | 3/10/2017 8:00:00 AM | 14.16                 | 13.67                | 3/8/2017 3:25:37 PM | 3/8/2017 6:41:59 PM | 0003
3  | xyz.a    | 3/8/2017 2:00:00 PM | 3/10/2017 8:00:00 AM | 14.16                 | 13.67                | 3/8/2017 3:25:37 PM | 3/8/2017 6:41:59 PM | 0003
```

the output table should be like :

```
ID | location | downtime_start        | downtime_end           | power_before_downtime|   power_after_downtime| creation_time        | end_time 
      |ser_request |  Adj Start date        |   Adj end date           |  Adj DC power

1  | xyz.a    | 3/8/2017 2:00:00 PM   | 3/10/2017 8:00:00 AM   | 14.16                |   13.67              |3/8/2017 3:25:37 PM    |  3/8/2017 6:41:59 PM| 0003       | 3/8/2017 2:00:00 PM    |  3/10/2017 8:00:00 AM    |     14.16

2  |  xyz.a   |  3/8/2017 2:00:00 PM  |   3/10/2017 8:00:00 AM |    14.16
```

|   13.67                |  3/8/2017 3:25:37 PM  |3/8/2017 6:41:59 PM  | 0003
|       0       |       0       |   0

```
3  |  xyz.a   |    3/8/2017 2:00:00 PM|   3/10/2017 8:00:00 AM |   14.16
```

|  13.67     3/8/2017 3:25:37 PM |   3/8/2017 6:41:59 PM| 0003|     0   |   0   |       0

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? (Don't tag products not involved.)

Comment: I can't read those pictures' tiny text. (Most people here want formatted text, not images...)

Comment: i am using MS SQL 2010

Comment: Please *[edit]* your question to include sample data. It's unreadable in the comments. (Ideally, a code block with a `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements would be best).

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: i have added the data in the question

Comment: you will have to edit the question and post it ,not in comments

Comment: see the link referenced to know on , how to ask a perfect question:https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: There are no MS SQL 2010. Only MS SQL 2008R2 and MS SQL 2012

Comment: please describe what is `ADJ` function. In SQL there no such aggregate. What differece between `downtime_start` and `Adj Start date`. If it equals you can do a simple update

Comment: @MikhailLobanov: they both are the same its just the **naming convention **i am using.  ADJ stands for Adjacent values .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE T
SET 
[Adj Start date] = downtime_start,
[Adj end date]   = downtime_end,
[Adj DC power]   = power_before_downtime
FROM (
    SELECT [Adj Start date], [Adj end date], [Adj DC power], downtime_start, downtime_end, power_before_downtime, 
        rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY downtime_start, downtime_end ORDER BY id) 
    FROM dbo.TB1
) T
WHERE rn = 1
```

If you need to select a data, use `CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN downtime_start ELSE 0 END`

Comment: i am getting an error as inavlid column name for all the three columns

Comment: @Looking_for_answers I've edited my query and add five missing columns. Please provide full error message if error appears